# How to catch the the event while user clicks back button in mobile in JS

Tags: button, jquery-mobile

I wish to detect while user clicks backbutton in mobile,Please provide me a solution how to catch the event while user clicks back button in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a phonegap app and needed a similar solution so I use this function:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", stopBack, false);
function stopBack() /* Stops user navigating pages using back button on device */{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyPressed, false);

    function backKeyPressed() {

        //Do some stuff

    }
}
```

Hope that this helps